# How can I judge my server performance in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Concurrent users : 2000
Ramp up period:10 sec
loop :1

The summary report for above is:

Average :2000

min :4

max :19964

**Error:17.50%** // this error are Java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Through put:67.2 sec

From this result can I infer that my server cannot handle load of 2000 users ?

Comment: Is the scenario matching the actual use of the application like there will be pause between two action of a single user.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 20 seconds response time and 20% error rate my expectation is that your application under test is overloaded. Personally I would go for the following steps:

1. Re-run the test using larger ramp-up time, generate [Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) after the run and correlate increasing load with the other KPIs like:

   - what was the maximum throughput (how many requests per second could system server) and what was amount of active users at this time
   - what was the number of users when error start occurring
   - what is relationship between amount of users and response time
   - etc.
2. The next step would be determining the [bottleneck](http://www.performancetestingfun.com/bottleneckanalysis/) i.e. why application responds slowly or not responds at all. The reasons could be in:

   - Application simply lacks resources (CPU, RAM, network or disk IO or starts swapping). A good practices is monitoring the system health i.e. with [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
   - Configuration of software (application/web server, database, load balancer, etc.) is not appropriate for high loads. Each of software components needs to be appropriately tuned for high loads
   - Your application code is not optimal, you can re-run your test with [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) telemetry to see what are the largest objects, the slowest functions, etc.
   - It can be something absolutely external like faulty router, bad network cable, using WiFi instead of LAN, hitting corporate proxy limits, etc.